# How to get update specific file in revision length?

Tags: svn

I'm trying checkout specific file in length of revesion number following

In SVN have:

```
   revision
     1024
       - Modify /trunk/apps/model/book.rb
     1023
       - Modify /trunk/apps/model/book.rb
       - Modify /trunk/config/locale/en.rb
     1022
       - Modify /trunk/apps/model/note.rb
     1021
       ....
```

How do I checkout specific file from SVN with revision between 1023 to 1024 with result below?

```
trunk
  - app
  - - model
  - - - book.rb
  - config
  - - locale
  - - - en.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not checkout a single file. The smallest part you can checkout is a directory. In this case i would suggest to checkout the trunk in revision 1024 which contains all files till revision 1024...but will also contain the note.rb which you don't like to have. It is not possible  to checkout the state as you described it. I don't know why you need to have only this state of your working copy with only files which have been changed in 1023 and 1024...which sound a little bit like a delta checkout...